# Flutter ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart, themedata

I want to set a ThemeData in my project but I can't set the correct background color. I think that the problem is about brightness....

```
theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme(
          primary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          onBackground: Colors.white,
          onError: Colors.yellow,
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Colors.white,
          background: Colors.yellow,
          secondary: Colors.purple,
          surface: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          secondaryVariant: Colors.white,
          error: Colors.red,
          primaryVariant: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          onPrimary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
      ),
```

Brightness can't be null so how can I solve to have the right color in background?
I read that background for ThemeData has a space between element when I scroll down. So how can I set the ThemeData background correctly for my scaffold?

Comment: What do you mean by the "background color"? If you are using a `Scaffold` the color you are looking for is `scaffoldBackgroundColor`, if you are using a `Card`, it is `cardColor`, if you are using a `Material` widget it is `canvasColor`. And there are other widgets and "backgroundColor" possible. The best way is to look in the source code of the widget you are using to see how it takes its background color

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `scaffoldBackgroundColor` of your `themeData` like so.

```
theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme(
          primary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          onBackground: Colors.white,
          onError: Colors.yellow,
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Colors.white,
          background: Colors.yellow,
          secondary: Colors.purple,
          surface: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          secondaryVariant: Colors.white,
          error: Colors.red,
          primaryVariant: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          onPrimary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `ThemeData`, use `Theme.of(context).copyWith()`. Also, I would say use `themeMode` and `darkTheme`.

> Rather than overriding everything, it often makes sense to extend the parent theme. You can handle this by using the copyWith() method.

```dart
 theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
          primary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          onBackground: Colors.white,
          onError: Colors.yellow,
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Colors.white,
          background: Colors.yellow,
          secondary: Colors.purple,
          surface: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          secondaryVariant: Colors.white,
          error: Colors.red,
          primaryVariant: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          onPrimary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
```

for more [themes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the code like below

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
      primary: Color(0xffbb86fc),
      primaryVariant: Color(0xff3700B3),
      secondary: Color(0xffcf6679),
      secondaryVariant: Color(0xff03dac6),
      surface: Color(0xffcf6679),
      background: Color(0xff121212),
      error: Color(0xffcf6679),
      onPrimary: Colors.black,
      onSecondary: Colors.black,
      onSurface: Colors.white,
      onBackground: Colors.white,
      onError: Colors.black,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  ),
  home: const YourPage(), 
);
```

in this case any property is not required so change the colors as you wish.